# Webpack4|Redux|React Issue - You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, redux

I am trying my hands on Webpack4/Redux/React and getting the following error for my sample application:

> ./src/index.js] 210 bytes {main} [built] [failed] [1 error]
>       + 13 hidden modules
>
> ERROR in ./src/index.js Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:16)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. | import
>   React from 'react'; | | const element =
>
> ## Hello, world
>
> ; | |  @
>   multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000
>   webpack/hot/only-dev-server ./src/index i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

I have tried different ways to resolve this (as is evident from commented out code) without any success. Please let me know what I am missing. My Code files are as follows:

**Package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "react-redux-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "using redux architecture",
  "main": "node server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "reactjs",
    "redux",
    "react",
    "hot",
    "reload",
    "live",
    "edit",
    "webpack"
  ],
  "author": "newbieToReact",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "react": "^16.4.0",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "webpack": "^4.10.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var devFlagPlugin = new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  __DEV__: JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(process.env.DEBUG || 'true'))
});

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './src/index'
  ],
  mode: "development",
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    //new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    devFlagPlugin,
    new ExtractTextPlugin('app.css')
  ],
//  module: {
//    loaders: [
//      {
//        test: /\.jsx?$/,
//        loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
//        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
//      },
//      { test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css-loader?module!cssnext-loader') }
//    ]
//  },


//module: {
//    rules: [
//      {
//        exclude: '/node_modules/',
        //test: /\.jsx?$/,
        //test: /\.js$/,
//        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
//        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
//        test: /\.css$/,
//        use: [
//          { loader: "react-hot" },
//          { loader: "babel" },
//          { loader: "ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css-loader?module!cssnext-loader')"},
//          { loader: "style-loader" },
//        ]
//      }
//    ]
//  },


module: {
    rules: [
      {
        exclude: '/node_modules/',
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: "react-hot",
        loader: "babel",
        loader: "ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css-loader?module!cssnext-loader')",
        loader: "style-loader",
      }
    ]
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.json']
  }
};
```

**src/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const element = <h1>Hello, world</h1>;
```

Comment: You just wrote `loader:` 4 times. If you know anything about objects you would know that you can't have multiple items with the same key. Secondly did you look at the webpack docs which show clearly how to use multiple loaders? Next you are writing `ExtractTextPlugin.extract` as a string, but it's a function... same JS principles apply to webpack configs, and did you look at the docs on their github? I recommend you follow the webpack quickstart guide.

Answer (score 3):

Your `module/loaders` needs another clause in `test:` this needs to be `test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,` because you are using a `.js` file and no `.jsx`. Also it's a good practice to include this in your config: `resolve: { extensions: ['.js'] },` when using `.js` instead off `.jsx`. Also uncomment the second loader because i see you're using a `.css` this needs the `css-loader` to work.

You will have to add `css-loader` and `babel-loader` to your devDependencies aswell.

Also you're using `webpack 4` which implies that `ExtractTextPlugin` has been deprecated so remove this.

Hope this helped, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In `webpack.config.js` you should follow scheme described in [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/)

Here is an example

```
  rules: [{
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
  }, {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
  }]
```